# How to get a re-organizing d3 plot to return the correct .on value?

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny

After selecting an Airline input on the top left of the dashboard different than the initial ("Delta Air Lines Inc."), clicking the bars on the right do not return the correct label shown to the left of the bar.

I added `observe()`'s in `server()` to print out the value being returned by d3. It looks like it's stuck returning the very first table's values. I suspect something about the D3 plot is not reactive to the changing Airlines?

**bar_plot.js**

```
var layer_left = 0.35;
var layer_left_text = 0.01;
var layer_top = 0.1;
var layer_height = 0.85;
var layer_width = 0.55;

var svgHeight = parseInt(svg.style('height'));
var svgWidth = parseInt(svg.style('width'));

var colLeft = svgWidth * layer_left;
var colTop = svgHeight * layer_top;
var colLeftText = svgWidth * layer_left_text;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y; })])
  .range([0, svgWidth * layer_width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.label; }))
  .range([0, svgHeight * layer_height])
  .padding(0.1);

// Bars

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .join(
    function(enter) {
      return enter
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.y); })
      .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth() * 0.9)
      .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.label) + colTop; })
      .attr('x', colLeft)
      .attr('fill', 'brown')
      .attr('opacity', function(d) { 
        return d.y / d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y; }); 
      })
      .attr('d', function(d) {return d.label; });
    }
  )
  .on('click', function(d) {
    Shiny.setInputValue(
      'bar_clicked', 
      d3.select(this).attr("d"),
      { priority: 'event' }
    );
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(){
        d3.select(this)
          .attr('fill', '#ffb14e');
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(){
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('fill', 'brown');
  })
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.y); })
  .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth() * 0.9)
  .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.label) + colTop; })
  .attr('x', colLeft)
  .attr('opacity', function(d) { 
    return d.y / d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y; }); 
  });

// Labels
svg.selectAll('.label')
  .data(data)
  .join(
    function(enter) {
      return enter
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('x', colLeftText)
      .attr('y', function(d) { 
        return yScale(d.label) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2 + colTop; 
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.label; })
      .style('font-size', '12px') 
      .style('font-family', 'sans-serif');
    }
  )
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr('x', colLeftText)
  .attr('y', function(d) { 
    return yScale(d.label) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2 + colTop;
  })
  .text(function(d) { return d.label; });

// Numeric labels

svg.selectAll('.value-label')
  .data(data)
  .join(
    function(enter) {
      return enter
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'value-label')
      .attr('x', function(d) { return colLeft + xScale(d.y) * 1.01; })
      .attr('y', function(d) { 
        return yScale(d.label) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2 + colTop; 
      })
      .style('font-size', '12px') 
      .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
      .text(function(d) { return d.y; });
    }
  )
  .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('x', function(d) { return colLeft + xScale(d.y) * 1.01; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { 
      return yScale(d.label) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2 + colTop; 
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.y; });


// Title
svg.append('text')
  .attr('x', svgWidth * 0.01)
  .attr('y', svgHeight * 0.05)
  .style('font-size', '18px') 
  .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
  .text('Top 10 Employees');

// Sub-title
svg.append('text')
  .attr('x', svgWidth * 0.99)
  .attr('y', svgHeight * 0.05)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .style('font-size', '12px') 
  .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
  .text('Click bar for details');
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
library(stringr)
library(DT)
library(r2d3)
library(nycflights13)

# Use purrr's split() and map() function to create the list
# needed to display the name of the airline but pass its
# Carrier code as the value

airline_list <- airlines %>%
  collect() %>%
  split(.$name) %>%
  map(~ .$carrier)

# Use rlang's set_names() to easily create a valide "choices"
# argument of the dropdown where the displayed text has to be
# different than the value passed as the input selection

month_list <- as.list(1:12) %>%
  set_names(month.name)

month_list$`All Year` <- 99

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Flights Dashboard",
    titleWidth = 200
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "airline",
      label = "Airline:",
      choices = airline_list,
      selected = "DL",
      selectize = FALSE
    ),
    sidebarMenu(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "month",
        label = "Month:",
        choices = month_list,
        selected = 99,
        size = 13,
        selectize = FALSE
      ),
      actionLink("remove", "Remove detail tabs")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tabs",
      tabPanel(
        title = "Main Dashboard",
        value = "page1",
        fluidRow(),
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 6,
            d3Output("group_totals")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            d3Output("top_airports")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tab_list <- NULL
  
  observeEvent(input$column_clicked, {
    print(paste0("You have chosen: ", input$column_clicked))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$bar_clicked, {
    print(paste0("You have chosen: ", input$bar_clicked))
  })
  # Use a reactive() function to prepare the base
  # SQL query that all the elements in the dashboard
  # will use. The reactive() allows us to evaluate
  # the input variables
  base_flights <- reactive({
    res <- flights %>%
      filter(carrier == input$airline) %>%
      left_join(airlines, by = "carrier") %>%
      rename(airline = name) %>%
      left_join(airports, by = c("origin" = "faa")) %>%
      rename(origin_name = name) %>%
      select(-lat, -lon, -alt, -tz, -dst) %>%
      left_join(airports, by = c("dest" = "faa")) %>%
      rename(dest_name = name)
    if (input$month != 99) res <- filter(res, month == input$month)
    res
  })

  # Montly/daily trend (server) -------------------------------------
  output$group_totals <- renderD3({
    grouped <- ifelse(input$month != 99, expr(day), expr(month))

    res <- base_flights() %>%
      group_by(!!grouped) %>%
      tally() %>%
      collect() %>%
      mutate(
        y = n,
        x = !!grouped
      ) %>%
      select(x, y)

    if (input$month == 99) {
      res <- res %>%
        inner_join(
          tibble(x = 1:12, label = substr(month.name, 1, 3)),
          by = "x"
        )
    } else {
      res <- res %>%
        mutate(label = x)
    }
    r2d3(res, "col_plot.js")
  })

  # Top airports (server) -------------------------------------------
  output$top_airports <- renderD3({
    # The following code runs inside the database
    base_flights() %>%
      group_by(dest, dest_name) %>%
      tally() %>%
      collect() %>%
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      head(10) %>%
      arrange(dest_name) %>%
      mutate(dest_name = str_sub(dest_name, 1, 30)) %>%
      rename(
        x = dest,
        y = n,
        label = dest_name
      ) %>%
      r2d3("bar_plot.js")
  })

  # Get details (server) --------------------------------------------
  get_details <- function(airport = NULL, day = NULL) {
    # Create a generic details function that can be called
    # by different dashboard events
    res <- base_flights()
    if (!is.null(airport)) res <- filter(res, dest_name == airport)
    if (!is.null(day)) res <- filter(res, day == !!as.integer(day))

    res %>%
      head(100) %>%
      select(
        month, day, flight, tailnum,
        dep_time, arr_time, dest_name,
        distance
      ) %>%
      collect() %>%
      mutate(month = month.name[as.integer(month)])
  }

  # Month/Day column click (server) ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$column_clicked != "", {
    if (input$month == "99") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "month", selected = input$column_clicked)
    } else {
      day <- input$column_clicked
      month <- input$month
      tab_title <- paste(
        input$airline, "-", month.name[as.integer(month)], "-", day
      )
      if (!(tab_title %in% tab_list)) {
        appendTab(
          inputId = "tabs",
          tabPanel(
            tab_title,
            DT::renderDataTable(
              get_details(day = day)
            )
          )
        )
        tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title)
      }
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected = tab_title)
    }
  },
  ignoreInit = TRUE
  )


  # Bar clicked (server) --------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$bar_clicked, {
    airport <- input$bar_clicked
    month <- input$month
    tab_title <- paste(
      input$airline, "-", airport,
      if (month != 99) {
        paste("-", month.name[as.integer(month)])
      }
    )
    if (!(tab_title %in% tab_list)) {
      appendTab(
        inputId = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          tab_title,
          DT::renderDataTable(
            get_details(airport = airport)
          )
        )
      )

      tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title)
    }
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected = tab_title)
  })

  # Remote tabs (server) --------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    # Use purrr's walk command to cycle through each
    # panel tabs and remove them
    tab_list %>%
      walk(~ removeTab("tabs", .x))
    tab_list <<- NULL
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```